# FastCGI launcher

Tags: linux, nginx, fastcgi, spawn-fcgi

I need to serve some FCGI scripts (via [WSAPI](http://wsapi.luaforge.net/), but that is irrelevant) from nginx.

Currently I'm using [spawn_fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) to do this. This is the only solution I've found.

I need to know my other options. Are there any other ways to run FastCGI under nginx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally prefer to decouple my FCGI processes from the webserver as much as possible, and manage them as I would any other daemon.  In my case, I've switched all of that sort of thing to use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), because it's small, lightweight, is *very* reliable, and does exactly what you need in this instance, with no mess or fuss.

Comment: Thanks for daemontools! I had re-invented the wheel twice, and you've just pointed me at the solution :)

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. Have you compared performance with other solutions?

Comment: There's no performance difference, because the actual operation of the FCGI process is the same.  Increased performance comes from multiple FCGI listeners load-balanced in the frontend, or else one FCIG listener that delegates requests to multiple threads or child processes.  This is out of scope for a discussion of the launcher, though.

Comment: Out of scope, indeed. But I want to read up on the subject. Do you have a link? (I'll create a new question if needed.)

Comment: Definitely worth a new question.

Comment: @Alexander: did you create a new question like you mentioned above? i searched all your questions but did not find it, also i searched all of Mr womble's answers but no luck.

Comment: Nope. Please do, and post a link here so we all can follow.

Answer (score 2):

Yet again nobody mentioned [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org). It's now bundled with php itself so you should read [docs about php-fpm in PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php).

Comment: Yeah, php-fpm is great FastCGI process manager.

Comment: for PHP, it is the best way to execute the zend engine.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially there's cgi-fcgi.  What don't you like about the current method you're using?

Comment: Not that I don't like something specific... I have not enough data for that (yet). I've just overheard some vague and unspecific negative opinions about spawn_fcgi. I'm trying to find out what else I can use just in case.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about high load (up to C10K) situation.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically, there are 3 options how PHP can be attached to nginx:

1. Module. Currently, there's no nginx PHP module. Minus.
2. CGI. PHP is spawned at every request, and a single php process parses a single php file. execve() overhead is obvious. Dirty Plus.
3. FCGI. Pre-spawned processes which handle requests, and never stop. Plus.

There's 2 methods of creating these FCGI processes:

1. Pre-launch them. That's what spawn_fcgi does, and that is okay.
2. Let nginx launch them: nginx tries to connect to localhost:, and if there's nobody listening, spawns php FCGI workers. That would have been better in terms of administration comfort and stability, but I've never heard of such a module for nginx :) Maybe, you'll be the first one to develop it? ;)

spawn script is not evil, really :)

P.S. Походу, самый пытливый ум у русских ;)

Comment: That does not matter, of course, but I do not use PHP (but do use Lua, via WSAPI).

Comment: Regarding auto-launching of FCGI processes by nginx. Can you please elaborate? Perhaps you have a link to a similar system description for another web-server?

Comment: No, the idea just came out of my head while I was writing this reply :) I've heard nothing of auto-spawning FCGI in nginx, nor with other httpd-s

Comment: Lighttpd does auto-spawning, and it's as bad an idea as it sounds.